# C# - ошибка 500 при запросе к сайту

Tags: c#, .net, httpclient, htmlagilitypack

Пытаюсь сделать запрос к сайту https://1clancer.ru через C#.

Библиотека **HtmlAgilityPack**:

```
var htmlWeb = new HtmlWeb();
var doc = htmlWeb.Load("https://1clancer.ru");

Console.WriteLine(doc.DocumentNode.InnerHtml);
```

Стандартная библиотека **HttpClient**:

```
var client = new HttpClient();
var html = client.GetAsync("https://1clancer.ru");

Console.WriteLine(html.Result);
```

Оба варианта приводят к ответу 500 от сервера.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При этом, при запросе через код на Питоне всё работает.

```
import requests

response = requests.get('https://1clancer.ru')
print(response.text)
```

Comment: `html.Result` - во-первых, вы выводите в консоль `HttpResponseMessage` (бездумное использование ключевого слова `var`), а не ее контент, во-вторых, никогда не используйте `.Result`, используйте `await`, в вашем случае `await html.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Серверу просто нужен HTTP заголовок `Accept`, просто скопировал его из логов Firefox. `User-Agent` необязателен здесь, но  пусть будет. Это особенность конкретного текущего сервера, и решение не относится ко всем сайтам интернета в целом.

Еще сервер возвращает ответ в древней кодировке `Content-Type: text/html; charset=windows-1251`, поэтому я подключил кодировки Windows через `RegisterProvider`. Это нужно сделать 1 раз при запуске приложения до начала всех запросов на сервер. (Если вы используйете древний Framework 4.x, то кодировка 1251 там подключена по умолчанию, ничего дополнительно подключать не требуется).

```
private static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler { AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.All });

static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.UserAgent.ParseAdd("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:101.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/101.0");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.ParseAdd("text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8");

    string html = await client.GetStringAsync("https://1clancer.ru");

    HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument(); // HtmlAgilityPack
    doc.LoadHtml(html);
    string title = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//title").InnerText;
    Console.WriteLine(title);
}
```

`HttpClient` и `DefaultRequestHeaders` к нему тоже достаточно создать один раз на все время работы приложения. Далее пользоваться одним и тем же клиентом в разных запросах.

Ответ от сервера `200 OK`, вывод в консоль

```
Сервис удаленной работы для 1С программистов (1С фриланс, 1C freelance). обслуживание 1С, 1С настройка, программирование 1С :: 1Clancer.ru
```